# Is c(0) short for c = 0?

Tags: c++

Example in this code ,i know c hold the count but i do not understand it's initialization. is it just short for c = 0?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int n, p, v, t, c(0);
    cin >> n;
    while(n--){
        cin >> p >> v >> t;
        if(p+v+t >=2)
            c++;
    }
}
```

Comment: How can `c(0)` (four characters) possibly be *short* for `c=0` (three characters). Do you think "June" is short for "JUN"?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Don't you know very long shortcuts?

Comment: @Deduplicator No, but I do know a very short longcut.

Comment: You may want to view the Nicolai Josuttis [The Nightmare of Initialization in C++](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7DTlWPgX6zs) presentation.  (1 hour.)  He covers all the different initialization syntaxes in C++.